# загрузка потока через hls.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hls

У меня на странице есть плеер hls. Дело в том что он одни потоки грузит, а другие нет например:
http://live2.mediacdn.ru/sr1/grozny/chunklist_b1498000.m3u8" - загружает
http://demo1.cdn.micro.im:63080/tXOTRkENh6dQf045/animalfamilyhd/chunklist.m3u8 - не загружает

Расширение для Google chrome Play HLS M3u8 использует тот же самый плеер и загружает 2 потока одинаково, в чем проблема. Зарание спасибо.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
  <video id="video" autoplay, loop, controls></video>
  <script>
    if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      var video = document.getElementById('video');
      var hls = new Hls();
      // bind them together
      hls.attachMedia(video);
      hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {
        console.log("video and hls.js are now bound together !");
        hls.loadSource("http://live2.mediacdn.ru/sr1/grozny/chunklist_b1498000.m3u8");
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {
          console.log("manifest loaded, found " + data.levels.length + " quality level");
        });
      });     
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ошибки в js-консоли есть?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://demo1.cdn.micro.im:63080/tXOTRkENh6dQf045/animalfamilyhd/chunklist.m3u8' from origin 'http://testlocal' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Вот в тексте ошибки причина и написана, сервер запрещает вам запускать поток на вашем сайте